# Select query result should return based on passing parameters in procedures without using if else statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    id,
    starttime,
    endtime,
    name
from 
    table1
where
    id != 0 
    and starttime >= @startdate and endtime <= @enddate
```

In the above query, how do I perform if the `@startdate` and `@enddate` parameter is null by without using if else?

`starttime >= @startdate and endtime <= @enddate` this condition **should check if @startdate and @enddate is not null. else it won't to check.**

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: are you looking for `starttime >= ISNULL(@startdate,starttime) and endtime <= ISNULL(@enddate,endtime)` , not as answer since your question seems unclear.

Answer (score 1):

you simply check that the variable is null thus returning true as as appropriate

doing this individually for each parameter

```
where (startdate >= @startdate or @startdate is null)
and (enddate <= @enddate or @enddate is null)
```

you could also 'ignore' the criteria if either are null

```
where ((startdate >= @startdate and enddate <= @enddate)
or @startdate is null
or @enddate is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` function in the `where` condition.

```
select id,
starttime,
endtime,
name
from table1
where
id != 0 and
starttime >= ISNULL(@startdate,starttime) and endtime <= ISNULL(@enddate,endtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add extra condition:

```
and @startdate is not null and @enddate is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

for this
**should check if @startdate and @enddate is not null. else it won't to check** use first answer

if `@startdate` is null then it will return `true` and gives all result

```
select id,
starttime,
endtime,
name
from table1
where
id != 0 and
(starttime >= @startdate or @startdate is null )
and 
(endtime <= @enddate or @enddate is null)
```

or

```
select id,
starttime,
endtime,
name
from table1
where
id != 0 and
(starttime >= @startdate and @startdate is NOT null )
and 
(endtime <= @enddate and @enddate is NOT  null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OR to check this:

```
where
(id != 0) 
and
(
     (@startdate IS NULL) OR (@enddate IS NULL)
     OR 
     (starttime >= @startdate and endtime <= @enddate)
)
```